# Async function inside return of promise

Tags: react-native, asynchronous, promise, async-await

I am trying to call an async. function inside the return of a promise:

```
async _TestFunction(id){

return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    promise = await _SomeOtherFunction(); 

});
```

Is there any way how I can handle this? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you were trying to return the `promise` variable, and this is (more or less) a representative example:

```
async _TestFunction(id){
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    promise = await _SomeOtherFunction();
    res(promise);
  });
}
```

Then this is probably how you would want to write this instead:

```
async _TestFunction(id){
  promise = await _SomeOtherFunction();
  return promise;
}
```

Which can be further simplified:

```
_TestFunction(id){
  return _SomeOtherFunction();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this nice example!